# How to filter search criteria for Web Browsing in Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to make a basic search program to demonstrate to a colleague. But for some reason, I am having difficulty applying a "filter" to the search program. Right now, I am filtering out amazon and games for a pseudo work environment. When I run my code and search for amazon.com, it says "Invalid Search Criteria. Try Again." which is perfect. But on the second try, it still says "Invalid Search Criteria. Try Again." but then completes the search. Even if I am not searching amazon or games. How can I make the code react appropriately?

Example:

```
import webbrowser

search=input('Search: ')

while search == str('amazon') or str('games'):
  print('Invalid search criteria. Try again')

  if search != str('amazon') or str('games'):
    webbrowser.open('http://'+search)
```

Comment: Why are you using a while loop?

Comment: I wanted the code to keep telling the person that what they were searching was invalid instead of only allowing a one time search.

Comment: You've used the while loop in the wrong place, see pkqxdd's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to convert string to string with expressions like `str('amazon')`.

Second, Pythonic way for for your `if` statement is

```
if search in ('amazon', 'games'):
```

Third - you probably want from your program to not stop after the first correct answer, but to allow user ask other and other one - almost infinitely, until the user just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (= empty string), so your program may be something as:

```
import webbrowser

while True:
    search=input('Search: ')
    if not search:                  # Means search is not empty
        break;                      # Jump from your infinite loop

    if search in ('amazon', 'games'):
        print('Invalid search criteria. Try again')
    else:
        webbrowser.open('http://'+search)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to use simple if-else branching:

```
import webbrowser
while True:
    search=input('Search: ')
    if search == 'amazon' or search == 'games':
        print('Invalid search criteria. Try again')

    else:
        webbrowser.open('http://'+search)
```

Also it may be a good idea to change the condition to `'amazon' in search or 'games' in search` to handle input better

Comment: I am still receiving the message that my search criteria is invalid. Even if I do not type in amazon or games. What could cause this issue?